# XML Serialization - not expected error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, serialization

I am trying to serialize an ASMX web service result, but I get the following error.

```
 There is an error in XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:     <ArrayOfT_SATQuestionInfo xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'> was not expected
```

Any idea on how to fix this so it will 'expect' the namespace?

Comment: You are probably not successfully serializing anything in the first place.  That exception often occurs when what you think is XML actually contains some error output.  Can you post additional details?

Comment: That looks to me more like you're getting malformed xml. What does the xml look like?

Comment: How about this error.  My xml file saved incorrectly, but I now have this error.

Comment: Show us the XML you're getting, and the code you're using to serialize it!

Comment: `My xml file saved incorrectly`.  Put it in the shredder.

Comment: if you are getting the object, try using the <a href='http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx'>Built-in Serialzier </a>

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me that the problem is with deserialization, in this case on client side. I would suggest you to isolate the problem and I am allmost certain that error will be reproduced. Just make a simple test using console application. Fill your object as you do inside web servise, do xml serialization and then try to deserialize back to object. Error that you are experiencing can be caused by invalid data inside xml or invalid structure that can not be deserialized back to object.